# XSLT - Transform an XML document to have elements ordered alphabetically

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML document using XSLT to get the 'entry' elements to be ordered alphabetically using their key.

An example of my XML is as follows:

```
<Custom name="Custom Name1">
    <Attributes>
        <Map>
            <entry key="entry4">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String13</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="entry1">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String6</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="entry2">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String5</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="entry3">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String2</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
        </Map>
    </Attributes>
</Custom>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is the following result:

```
<Custom name="Custom Name1">
    <Attributes>
        <Map>
            <entry key="entry1">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String6</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="entry2">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String5</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="entry3">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String2</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="entry4">
                <value>
                    <Map>
                        <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
                        <entry key="Entitlements">
                            <value>
                                <List>
                                    <String>String13</String>
                                </List>
                            </value>
                        </entry>
                        <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
                    </Map>
                </value>
            </entry>
        </Map>
    </Attributes>
</Custom>
```

I have attempted to use the following XSLT to transform my XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Custom/Attributes/Map">
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@key" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>      
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's working to order the elements as I would like, however it then appears to be removing the map element, giving me an output of the following:

```
<Custom name="Custom Name1">
   <Attributes>
      <entry key="entry1">
         <value>
            <Map>
               <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
               <entry key="Entitlements">
                  <value>
                     <List>
                        <String>String6</String>
                     </List>
                  </value>
               </entry>
               <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
            </Map>
         </value>
      </entry>
      <entry key="entry2">
         <value>
            <Map>
               <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
               <entry key="Entitlements">
                  <value>
                     <List>
                        <String>String5</String>
                     </List>
                  </value>
               </entry>
               <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
            </Map>
         </value>
      </entry>
      <entry key="entry3">
         <value>
            <Map>
               <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
               <entry key="Entitlements">
                  <value>
                     <List>
                        <String>String2</String>
                     </List>
                  </value>
               </entry>
               <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
            </Map>
         </value>
      </entry>
      <entry key="entry4">
         <value>
            <Map>
               <entry key="Active" value="true"/>
               <entry key="Entitlements">
                  <value>
                     <List>
                        <String>String13</String>
                     </List>
                  </value>
               </entry>
               <entry key="Refresh" value="true"/>
            </Map>
         </value>
      </entry>
   </Attributes>
</Custom>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks,
Connor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You matched `Map`, but you don't copy or create a new map element. Just add xsl:copy and you should be good to go...

```xml
  <xsl:template match="/Custom/Attributes/Map">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@key" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBHw